# creating a folder to upload file on a linux server with tomcat8

Tags: java, file, spring-boot, tomcat8

I have a spring boot web application where the user needs to upload a file and I have to save it to the server in a **upload-dir** folder 
this is what I tried to do

```
public String store(MultipartFile file, String newName) {
this.rootLocation = System.getProperty("user.dir") + File.separator + "upload-dir";
        try {
            if (file.isEmpty()) {
                throw new StorageException("Failed to store empty file " + file.getOriginalFilename());
            }
            if (!Files.exists(this.rootLocation))
                Files.createDirectory(this.rootLocation);
            Files.copy(file.getInputStream(), this.rootLocation.resolve(newName));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.console().writer().write(e.getMessage());
            throw new StorageException("Failed to store file " + file.getOriginalFilename(), e);

        }
        return this.rootLocation.resolve(newName).toString();
    }
```

This work perfectly on localhost (windows) but when I deploy it to a remote *tomcat8* server running on Linux it fails !! any idea

Comment: How does it fail?

Comment: " it fails" means? Any error or?

Comment: i throws FileNotFound Exception

Comment: Verifiy if isn't a permission error.